Why isn't PyCharm properly recognizing my project?
I have several Python projects on my computer, all of which have been working as-expected for at least a few months. Recently I restarted my computer and when I try to open one of those projects (only one project; the rest all work correctly), there are two problems:

It changed how the directory is displayed. On the left, instead of showing all the folders and subfolders (when I click into them) and their files, it instead shows folders as dropdowns at the top and only files on the left (screenshot attached), and,
When I attempt to use CTRL+F to search the whole project for text, it cannot find ANY matching results, even if I'm directly copying from the page currently on display (screenshot attached).

The directory layout has changed to something difficult to navigate
The project-wide search functionality does not work
I do not have this problem with either other project, which is what makes it so confusing to me. I have tried reloading the project, restarting my computer, and checking for PyCharm updates, but none of them worked.

Which PyCharm IDE are you using? Because your Screenshots has the old UI I can guess two Ways to solve the Problem: 1. Update your PyCharm Version to something new, 2. if you can not update or this does not solve your problem: Go with fileexplorer to your project directory, delete the .idea Folder and import the project new to pycharm. With the second approach all your custom project settings are deleted. So be careful with it.

PS.: With the term "updating" I mean not to update your 2019.x build or what ever you have, I mean to install the new build. https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/
